# Get App Version with PlistBuddy returns "CFBundleShortVersionString does not exist"

Tags: ios, terminal, plist

I know this is an easy and silly question but I can't find why I'm getting error. I want to print the app version of a project after getting `xcarchive` file. I'm using `PlistBuddy` for that.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" /build/My_Project.xcarchive/Info.plist
```

This code returns

> Print: Entry, "CFBundleShortVersionString", Does Not Exist

However, I can successfully print "ApplicationProperties" or whole plist file. What can be the problem?

Comment: Is the path correct? Perhaps it should be `./build/My_Project.xcarchive/Info.plist` ?

Comment: Yes. I can successfully print plist or "ApplicationProperties"

Comment: Simple typo in  “CFBundleSortVersionString”– can you spot it?

Comment: Sorry, I write it wrong when writing question. It is giving same error.

Comment: Always nice if someone does not **copy/paste** the real code :( – Are you sure that the key exists? Check with `plutil -p /build/My_Project.xcarchive/Info.plist`

Answer (score 3):

The `CFBundleShortVersionString` property is stored inside `ApplicationProperties` dictionary, and PlistBuddy help says:

> ```
> Entries consist of property key names delimited by colons.  Array items
> are specified by a zero-based integer index.  Examples:
>     :CFBundleShortVersionString
>     :CFBundleDocumentTypes:2:CFBundleTypeExtensions
> ```

So, in order to get this value you need to run following command:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print ApplicationProperties:CFBundleShortVersionString" /build/My_Project.xcarchive/Info.plist
```